# Django - extend user profile error user has no attribute userprofile

Tags: python, django

Im following this link here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone

I didnt need the user section only the profile. the error im currently getting is

```
'User' object has no attribute 'UserProfile'
line 45: profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.UserProfile)
```

Which i understand is because the user model does not have a UserProfile. 
Im not sure how to get the UserProfile into the request so the form will work?

model

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    mpls_m_subscriptions = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="MPLS Maintenance Subscription",choices=settings.SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE,blank=True,null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.UserProfile.save()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from home.models import UserProfile

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('mpls_m_subscriptions',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db import transaction
from django.http import HttpResponse
from home.forms import ProfileForm
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.UserProfile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.UserProfile)
    return render(request, 'home/profile.html', {
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

Comment: Try `request.user.userprofile` instead.  Auto-generated related field names are converted to lower case by Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get userprofile by attribute name, not the model name:

```
...
else:
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
```

This might help, also u can set [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument, when creating a field, so the attribute name will correspond to that name.

Answer (score -1):

Use primary_key of UserProfile class then it will work. Don't use UserProfile class directly in request.user

```
profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.user_profile_primary_key)
```